# Many-to-Many relationship class table- automatically fill in?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, editing, relationship-class

Is there a way that the table of a many-to-many relationship class can automatically be filled in without me selecting the elements connected? 
So far I am using this method: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21708

But this takes lot of time, and I have huge amount of data, it's just not efficient to select every pole and connect it to every cable:P

PS: the cables and the poles are connected in a geometric network, can't arcgis figure out from that which one is connected to which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the exact same problem, the answer is here:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/55873-Populating-a-many-to-many-relationship?p=193958#post193958